# Advice on structuring a single-client server application

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, websocket, server

I am making an application which a user is meant to interact with in order to collect various data (compile data from several physical devices in various ways).

To do this, I decided on a web-based user interface, so most of the app is running on a "server" which controls the devices, and communicates with this `Javascript` UI using websockets. I have written this server in `Python` using `Autobahn` (among various other packages for dealing with the devices).

The application naturally has a lot of state: when to collect data, what data to collect, where to put it, etc.

Disregarding all of the code for the devices, the main server is laid out like:

```
.
├── handlers
│   ├── handler1.py
│   └── handler2.py
├── router.py
└── server.py
```

Right now I have the main server object (an `Autobahn` `WebSocketServerFactory`), which owns the state as an enum. It also owns a router, which it passes incoming messages from the client to. The router routes these messages to the correct handler, which reacts to the message and sends a response.

The handlers need to have access to the server's state, and also be able to change it. However giving a reference to the server object to each of the handlers feels like bad form (e.g. if I want to import the server in the handlers in order to do static type checking, then I get circular imports: `server -> router -> handler1 -> server`).

What is a well structured way to handle this with good form? Are there useful design patterns I should be trying to follow here that I am clearly ignoring?

Possibly of note: in order for the server to control the various devices I am using a publish/subscribe system. This makes it easy for the various handlers (and the classes I'm using to collect and store the data I want) to simply subscribe to a stream of data from a device.

Answer (score 0):

The global state for a whole server is a very bad idea. Imagine you have 100 clients and they are simultaneously send different requests. The race condition with server state would lead to denial of service in best or unpedictable answers in worst case. So you need somehow re-factor request routing and server behaviour. Server should dispatch requests to a handler if possible or put in a queue for some time or reject the request.

As a possible solution, router would collect similar requests then sent to handlers a bulk of work, switching internal state **of router** and then get results, updating its state and return data to server
Server (parse request)->router(has state)->handler1->router(has state)->server (prepare response)

**Update** I just note you have single client.

Anyway I suggest that server should not have the state and router (aka controller) dispatch to handlers denepnding on its internal state